# Get maximum value within rows based on a key value in JSONB?

Tags: postgresql

Using `jsonb`, is it possible to do a query that will get maximum value of a key within `jsonb` column? ex: get maximum age of key `age` in `{age: integer }`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `->>` operator to extract text from a JSONB column. From there on, it's just a matter of casting it to an `int` and apply `max` to it:

```
SELECT MAX((jsonb_col->>'age')::INT) FROM mytable
```